# I Learned Some Basics Of Pygame With Squares How Do I Get Started With Images?

Tags: python, pygame

my problem here is in my player I stated an direction statement if I am going right then blit right if I am going left then blit left movement BUT
when I am not clicking anything my player doesnt blit standing it keeps blitting left  or right I don't know why here is a [video](https://gyazo.com/636ea7a5b2fe02eea84c90e7d0b55d73)

```
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "left":
            window.blit(self.painfuls[self.anim_index],self.rect) 
            self.anim_index += 1 
            if self.anim_index == len(self.painfuls):
                self.anim_index = 0
        elif self.direction == "right":
            window.blit(self.painful[self.anim_index],self.rect) 
            self.anim_index += 1 
            if self.anim_index == len(self.painful): 
                self.anim_index = 0
        else:
            window.blit(self.standing[self.anim_index],self.rect) 
            self.anim_index += 1 
            if self.anim_index == len(self.standing):
                self.anim_index = 0
```

```
# import pygame
import pygame
pygame.init()


# window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("GHames")
painfuls = [
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0020.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0021.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0022.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0023.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0024.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0025.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0026.png")
        ]


standing = [
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0056.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0057.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0058.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0059.png")
        ]

standing = [
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0009.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0010.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0011.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0012.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0013.png")
        ]
coins = pygame.image.load("Coin.png")

bg = pygame.image.load("bgrs1.png")





# player class
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width  = width
        self.color = color
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.speed = 5
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.painful = [
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0009.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0010.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0011.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0012.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0013.png")
        ]
        self.painfuls = [
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0020.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0021.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0022.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0023.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0024.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0025.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0026.png")
        ]
        self.standing = [
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0056.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0057.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0058.png"),
        pygame.image.load("Sprite-0059.png")
        ]

        self.direction = "left"
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "left":
            window.blit(self.painfuls[self.anim_index],self.rect) 
            self.anim_index += 1 
            if self.anim_index == len(self.painfuls):
                self.anim_index = 0
        elif self.direction == "right":
            window.blit(self.painful[self.anim_index],self.rect) 
            self.anim_index += 1 
            if self.anim_index == len(self.painful): 
                self.anim_index = 0
        else:
            window.blit(self.standing[self.anim_index],self.rect) 
            self.anim_index += 1 
            if self.anim_index == len(self.standing):
                self.anim_index = 0


class enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color, self.rect)


class coin:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.coins = pygame.image.load("Coin.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,coins.get_width(),coins.get_height())
        self.coins = pygame.transform.scale(self.coins,(self.coins.get_width()//2,self.coins.get_height()//2))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.coins,self.rect)



class floor:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.rect)


class enemyplayer:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        selfwidth = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


# score for coins
font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32)
score = 0
text = font.render("score = " + str(score), True, (255,255,0))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (100,40)

# color
yellow = (255,255,0)
white = (255,255,255)
Green = (0,255,0)


# FPS
FPS  = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()



# defiine player class
enemyplayer1 = enemyplayer(280,390,40,40, Green)
enemos = [enemyplayer1]


playerman = player(50,390,30,30, Green)
enemy1 = enemy(150,390,150,10, white)
enemy2 = enemy(300,310,150,10, white)
enemy3 = enemy(50,260,150,10, white)
enemies = [enemy1,enemy2,enemy3]

# define floor class
floor1 = floor(-1000,510,1500,50, white)
flories = [floor1]
# coin class
coin1 = coin(180,370,20,20, yellow)
coin2 = coin(250,370,20,20, yellow)
coin3 = coin(360,290,20,20, yellow)
coin4 = coin(140,240,20,20, yellow)
Coins_list = [coin1,coin2,coin3,coin4]

# main loop

bullets = []
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False




    if playerman.y < 150:
        playerman.y += 1
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y += playerman.speed
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y += playerman.speed
        for floor in flories:
            floor.y += playerman.speed
        for enemyplayer in enemos:
            enemyplayer.y += playerman.speed

    if playerman.y > 450:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y -= playerman.fall
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y -= playerman.fall
        for floor in flories:
            floor.y -= playerman.fall
        for enemyplayer in enemos:
            enemyplayer.y -= playerman.fall




    if enemyplayer1.x > 150:
        enemyplayer1.x -= playerman.speed
    else:
        enemyplayer1.x < 250
        enemyplayer1.x += playerman.speed
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(enemyplayer1.rect):
        playerman.x = 50
        playerman.y = 390



    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()





    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerman.direction = "left"
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
        if playerman.x < 100:
            playerman.x += playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x += playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x += playerman.speed




    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerman.direction = "right"
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
        if playerman.x > 400:
            playerman.x -= playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x -= playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x -= playerman.speed




    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        collide = False
        for enemy in enemies:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.y = enemy.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.right + playerman.width:
                     playerman.x = enemy.rect.right
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(enemyplayer1.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.y = enemyplayer1.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > enemyplayer1.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < enemyplayer1.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemyplayer1.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < enemyplayer1.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > enemyplayer1.rect.right + playerman.width:
                     playerman.x = enemyplayer1.rect.right


            for one in range(len(Coins_list)-1,-1,-1):
                if playerman.rect.colliderect(Coins_list[one].rect):
                    del Coins_list[one]
                    score += 1
                    text = font.render("score = " + str(score), True, (255,255,0))
                    textRect = text.get_rect()
                    textRect.center = (100,40)   
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(floor1.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = floor1.rect.top - playerman.height  + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > floor1.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < floor1.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor1.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < floor1.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > floor1.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor1.rect.right





            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.JumpCount = 10
                playerman.y = 500- playerman.height

            if collide:
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    playerman.isJump = True
                playerman.fall = 0


    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount * abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.5
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10




    window.fill((130,0,0))

    for enemyplayer in enemos:
        enemyplayer.draw()
    for floor in flories:
        floor.draw()
    playerman.draw()
    window.blit(text,textRect)


    for coin in Coins_list:
        coin.draw()

    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.draw()



    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Do you want the player to have a animation or just one image for each direction

Comment: animation or anything for direction I just wanna know how I can apply it to my work I did for squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing each object to a image is easy, you can load the image with `pygame.image.load(filename)` and then put that on the screen.

In the player class, load the images and change the

```py
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.left_image = pygame.image.load("whatever_the_image_is_called.png")
        self.right_image = pygame.image.load("whatever_the_image_is_called.png")
        ...
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,left_image.get_width(), left_image.get_height())
        self.direction = "left" #set a stating direction
```

then to put them on the screen, blit them

```py
def draw(self):
    self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
    if self.direction == "left":
        screen.blit(self.left_image,self.rect)
    else:
        screen.blit(self.right_image,self.rect)
```

then when you change direction

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    playerman.direction = "left"

if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    playerman.direction = "right"
```

and for the other classes, you dont need the `self.direction` and they only have one direction so just blit the one image

As you can see, i used the image width and height instead of the `w` and `h` you pass as the parameter for the `self.rect`, so you can get rid of those, You will also have to make sure the image is the right size

You can use `pygame.transform.scale(image,size)` to resize the image to the right size

eg. `self.left_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.left_image,(100,100))`. this changes the image to 100x100, but it may become distorted so

```
self.left_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.left_image,(self.left_image.get_width()//2,self.left_image.get_height()//2))
```

this will scale the image to half the size, keeping the aspect ratio

For the animation, i find it best to use a list, then get each sprite, luckily you have named them well that you can do

```
self.left_anim = []
for i in range(2,10,1):
    self.left_anim.append(pygame.image.load("Sprite" + str(i).zfill(4)))
```

the `str(i).zfill(4)` makes it so it has 3 zeros in front

Then to go through the animation have an counter

```
self.anim_index = 0

def draw(self):
    screen.blit(self.left_anim[self.anim_index]) #put the current frame on screen
    self.anim_index += 1 #go to next frame
    if self.anim_index == len(self.left_anim): #if reached end of animation
        self.anim_index = 0 #reset
```

---

```
for i in range(2,10,1):
    self.painful.append[pygame.image.load("dots1.png"),[pygame.image.load("dots2.png"),[pygame.image.load("dots3.png"),[pygame.image.load("dots4.png"),[pygame.image.load("dots5.png")
```

the loop is so you dont need to have a `pygame.image.load()` for every image, you can just have one like

```
for i in range(1,5,1):
    self.painful.append(pygame.image.load("dots%d.png" %(str(1)))
```

or just have no loop

```
self.painful = [
    pygame.image.load("dots1.png"),
    pygame.image.load("dots2.png"),
    pygame.image.load("dots3.png"),
    pygame.image.load("dots4.png"),
    pygame.image.load("dots5.png")
]
```

then make sure you have the `self.rect.topleft =` outside the if statement as you want it to happen every frame, not just when the animation finishes

```
def draw(self):
    screen.blit(self.painful[self.anim_index],self.rect)) #put the current frame on screen
    self.anim_index += 1 #go to next frame
    if self.anim_index == len(self.painful): #if reached end of animation
        self.anim_index = 0 #reset
    self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y) #***** this part here ******
    pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)
```

Comment: wait so do I remove the isJump fall out of player??

Comment: @HabibIsmail no, the only thing you should delete is `pygame.draw.rect(...)`

Comment: thank you so much one problem tho when I removing right its all good but when I am moving left it blits the same image       self.left_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png")
 self.right_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png")

Comment: and also do I add images  to pygame.image.load to load in more images for animation?

Comment: @HabibIsmail cant believe i forgot about changing direction, updated the answer

Comment: I don't quit understand the animation one can you explain it more?

Comment: @HabibIsmail An animation is just a bunch of images one after another that makes the object look like its moving right. so we have the list of all the images, we just need to put them on the screen one by one. the `self.anim_index` loops through the list to get the next image and puts it on the screen. Once it reaches the end of the list, we have to reset it to 0 to start it again so the animation is constantly going. Does that make sense?

Comment: @HabibIsmail pretty much, just  small things to look out for that i added to answer

Comment: its giving me an error https://gyazo.com/cff0cc7086378c3ae130c3049532function missing required argument 'dest' (pos 2)e50f

Comment: [heres what I did ](https://gyazo.com/50582e79c6983bb66e05dde090f12eac)

Comment: @HabibIsmail The top link doesnt work, but it think the error is i forgot the location in `screen.blit(self.painful[self.anim_index],self.rect)`

Comment: ok that worked so I have my left right and standing so this is what I did I said if direction = left then blit that then if direction = right then blit that else if I am not clicking any other button it should blit this but I seem to get an error 'player' object has no attribute 'standing' https://gyazo.com/b8cdbbf8bf786cf4955866427f656f98 image of my script

Comment: wait I fixed the problem I forgot to add self.

Comment: @HabibIsmail Ah, the old self. that always happens. Also, it could be easier to just update the question with your code instead of making a video

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213892/discussion-between-the-big-kahuna-and-habib-ismail).